# Habilitar/Desabilitar input por id

Tags: jquery

Tenho dois inputs, ao clicar automaticamente eles se tornam readonly, estou fazendo assim:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#outros,#txtOutros', function() {
        $('#outros').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#txtOutros').attr('readonly', true);
    });
</script>
```

Mas quero que ao clicar no input #outros somente ele fique readonly e vice-versa.

Comment: O que está acontecendo no momento?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa quando clico em #outros por ex. tanto ele quanto o #txtOutros ficam readonly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá,

Faça assim

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#outros, #txtOutros', function() {
       $('#txtOutros, #outros').attr('readonly', false); 
       $(this).attr('readonly', true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: @Bia, Explicando o que eu fiz, primeiro eu coloco os dois como readonly = false e depois só deixo readonly no THIS, ou seja. no que foi clicado.

Comment: Simples e prático.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa entendi sim, muito bom! Estou começando com JQuery agora e as vezes me perco...

Answer (score 2):

jQuery <1.9

> $('#inputId').attr('readonly', true);

jQuery 1.9+

> $('#inputId').prop('readonly', true);

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306708/add-readonly-to-input-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Não seria melhor utilizar o atributo class? Por exemplo `class="bt"`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.bt', function() {
    $('.bt').attr('readonly', false); 
    $(this).attr('readonly', true);
});
```